# ECONNREFUSED Node.js server failing to connect to aws mysql instance

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, network-programming

I am trying to connect to a mysql database hosted by aws. I have no problem connecting with Mysql workbench, and I have allowed all traffic to the database in order to test, but I am still unable to connect with the server.

I have reproduced my error with this code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var db_config = require('../config/database')

var pool = mysql.createConnection(db_config);

pool.query("SELECT * FROM users", function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
}
})

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/Amin/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/Users/Amin/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
at Connection.connect (/Users/Amin/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
at Connection._implyConnect (/Users/Amin/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:453:10)
at Connection.query (/Users/Amin/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Amin/Projects/Relation-Quest/backend/tests/db-test.js:7:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

Any debug ideas?

Comment: It looks like it's trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:3306 but it should be connecting to the DNS address of the RDS instance.

Comment: I see what you're saying, the config file I'm importing has no reference to that ip though. I'll see what I can find

Comment: Still no luck, please let me know if you have any ideas

Comment: You need to expose the port `3306` of the instance in the security policy.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Please make sure that your credentials `key: value` are lowercase. For example:

`USERNAME: admin` ----> This is wrong.

`username: admin` ----> Correct.

Make sure all `key: value` pairs are lowercase.